# Security Sandbox violation for a Socket in AIR app?

Tags: apache-flex, air

I thought AIR applications ran in a trusted sandbox, but I am getting a security sandbox violation for a socket connection.  It used to work, off and on, but I just started messing with on old project again and now it doesn't work at all.

Targeting Flex 3 SDK with Flex Builder 4 beta.

socketIOError: Error #2031: Socket Error. URL: 174.37.152.44

socketSecurityError: Error #2048: Security sandbox violation: app:/mainMenu.swf cannot load data from :443.

Edit:  I found the problem.  It was an incorrect IP, and simply failing to connect.  Not sure why it gave me the sandbox violation error, but it was basically a bad error in that it didn't really have anything to due with the security sandbox.

Comment: What version of the flash player are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue had nothing to due with the security sandbox, the error was misleading.  I had the wrong IP.  There was no server listening at that IP, and it simply was failing to connect.